# mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, mount, azure

I try to mount a disk added to an Azure VM,
but it fails with the error message:

```
mount: /mydirectory: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Here is what I did: I created a disk and attached it to an Azure VM. 
I then ran the command `sudo fdisk -l`, which gave me this output:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 300 GiB, 322122547200 bytes, 629145600 sectors
Disk model: Virtual Disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Then, I called the command `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` with these steps

```
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.34).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xeacbff1b.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p): p
Partition number (1-4, default 1): 1
First sector (2048-629145599, default 2048):
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-629145599, default 629145599):

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 300 GiB.

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

After the `fdisk` call I tried to mount it (`sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mydirectory`) but it failed with the error message above:

```
mount:  wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I would suggest running `dmesg` to see if there is additional information that would indicate the problem. The error posted is too generic as to point to the exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a *new, **blank*** disk,
you need to create a filesystem on the partition
before you can mount it; e.g.,

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
```

would create an ext4 filesystem with default options on the partition.

Do not do this on a disk/partition that already has data on it!